# Should the currecy textbox in winforms gets rounding done all the time?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i have standard windows `textbox` that is formatted for currency but there is minor issue, when the user enter a value like **19999.9999999**, this get rounded to **20000.00**. If the user enters the value as **19999.99** this value will not get rounded. In the big industry, what is the correct way to format this number?

I need this to be rounded without harming the property value!

Comment: That sounds right to me. How would you expect it to round? Maybe you want it to truncate, rather than round?

Comment: So what output do you want ?

Comment: now this becomes interesting, this application originally deals with the real estate system. So these currency values are of property values. So how this should be done, i believe this shoudl be same as the banks

Comment: @PhillGreggan:- You need to show code and how you are formatting and rounding it!

Comment: i use the string.Format() with the CultureInfo enum with {0:C2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `Math.Round`.

try like this

```
decimal dValue = Math.Round(19999.999999M, 3);
```

Take a look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) for complete reference of `Math.Round()` method.

Comment: is this the way typical money systems handled?

Comment: yeah, most of the users are using this method to round up the amount. even there is no decimal or having more than 2 decimal.